# Access cannot create index

Tags: ms-access, indexing, duplicates, recordset

I have an access table (populated with data), that looks like this

[image]

The table contains about 7300 records. What I want to do now is to add a unique-index to all rows. The main reason for that is to ensure consistancy. There must not be any duplicate record. I do it like this:
[image]

Problem now is that access tells me, I cannot add the index because there is duplicate data in the table. Ok, now I need to find out what data is duplicate.
To do so I export the table and open it in excel and let it count similar columns per row:
[image]

What I do here is

- for each row count f- to e- columns that are equal to the a-column (column f - "Zählenwenn" means "CountIf")
- show a 1 if there are 4 equals or 0 otherwise (column g)

after summing up all g-rows, I see that there are 0 duplicate records. So I wonder why I cannot add an index to the table?

At least this was my approach to find duplicate records and the reason for not letting me add the index. Maybe it's wrong?

Why is access refusing to add the index? How can I find the reason?

Comment: I'd use the Access query assistant to find Duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

too bad I'm not using access much ;-)
of course the mentioned auery assistent did what I was looking for and worked well. thanks